# Create PDFdocument whith various pages format(iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to know how i can create document with different format pages. Example, i want add to pdf document format of A4 few pages format's A3. That is, in my document pages are A4, A3 then some, and then again A4.

```
|A4|

|A4|

|    |
|A3  |

|A4|

|A4|

|    |
|A3  |
```

If this i can't do this when i'm creating PDF, maybe i can add A3 in existing document and how?

How can i do this?

Now I am using the following construction for creating PDf:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rec = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
Document doc = new Document(rec, 72, 36, 100, 150);
doc.Open();
...
...
doc.Close();
```

Comment: The duplicate question gives you the code in Java, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt it to C#. Note that the page size only changes after you trigger a new page. You can't change the size of the current page. You can only change the size of the next page.

Comment: Thank you very much! It work!
Are you author of iText in Action? If that is right, then thank you so much. This book is great! First edition is funnny, i tell about "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

Comment: I am the author of that book, yes.

Comment: Sorry. I have got a question.
I'm changing rectangle and all new pages are changing rectangle, but when I return the value of the first value of the rectangle, then document ignoring mid value change of rectangle

That is:
            Document doc = new Document(recA4, 72, 36, 100, 150);
...
                    doc.SetPageSize(recA3Rotate);//don't work
                    doc.NewPage();
...

                    doc.SetPageSize(recA4);
                    doc.NewPage();


Maybe am i doing not right something?